# Implementing a simple 3 mode gate using Strawberry Fields

Tags: continuous-variable, strawberryfields

I'm looking to implement the operator the 3 mode operator $e^{-i\frac{s}{h}\hat{x_1} \otimes \hat{p_2} \otimes \hat{p_3}}$ using Strawberry Fields. I know that using the [`strawberryfields.ops.CXgate`](https://strawberryfields.ai/photonics/conventions/gates.html#id11) command I can implement the 2 mode [Controlled-X gate](https://strawberryfields.ai/photonics/conventions/gates.html#id11) defined as $e^{-i\frac{s}{h}\hat{x_1} \otimes \hat{p_2}}$, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the 3-mode operator be $\mathcal{O}_{123}(s)$. Dropping the tensor products and hat symbols here for convenience, one can apply the Fourier gate on the $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ mode, which I denote by $\mathcal{F}_k$ for the $k^{th}$ mode, i.e
$$
\mathcal{O}_{123}(s) = \mathcal{F}^{\dagger}_{3} \mathcal{F}^{\dagger}_{2} \mathcal{O'}_{123}(s) \mathcal{F}_2 \mathcal{F}_3
$$
where, $\mathcal{O'}_{123}(s) = e^{-i\frac{s}{h} x_1 x_2 x_3}$. Beyond this, some simple algebra allows you to decompose this product of position quadratures as,
$$
6x_1x_2x_3 = (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^3 - (x_1 + x_2)^3 - (x_1 + x_3)^3 - (x_2 + x_3)^3 + (x_{1}^3 + x_{2}^3 + x_{3}^3) 
$$
Exponentiating and performing a first order Trotter-Suzuki expansion allows us to *construct* (upto a marginal error that you can try and compute) $\mathcal{O'}_{123}(s)$, i.e,
$$
e^{-i\frac{s}{h}x_1 x_2 x_3} \approx e^{-i\frac{s}{6h}(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^3} \times e^{i\frac{s}{6h}(x_1 + x_2)^3} \times e^{i\frac{s}{6h}(x_1 + x_3)^3} \times e^{i\frac{s}{6h}(x_2 + x_3)^3} \times \prod_{r=1}^{3} \mathcal{V}_r \left( -\frac{s}{2} \right),
$$
which can be further decomposed in terms of the gates $\mathcal{CX}_{jm}(s) = e^{-i\frac{s}{h} x_j p_m}$ and the already mentioned cubic phase gates $\mathcal{V}_r(s_3) = e^{i\frac{s_3}{3h} x_{r}^3}$, which are ready to implement in Strawberry Fields. As an illustration, let us take the first term after expansion -
$$
\begin{align*}
e^{-i\frac{s}{6h}(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^3} &= \mathcal{CX}^{\dagger}_{12}(1) \left[ e^{-i\frac{s}{6h}(x_2 + x_3)^3} \right] \mathcal{CX}_{12}(1) \\
&= \mathcal{CX}^{\dagger}_{12}(1) \mathcal{CX}^{\dagger}_{23}(1) \left[ e^{-i\frac{s}{6h} x_{3}^3} \right] \mathcal{CX}_{23}(1) \mathcal{CX}_{12}(1) \\
&= \mathcal{CX}^{\dagger}_{12}(1) \mathcal{CX}^{\dagger}_{23}(1) \mathcal{V}_3(-s/2) \mathcal{CX}_{23}(1) \mathcal{CX}_{12}(1) 
\end{align*}
$$
And the other terms follow suit. Of course, this is not the only way to decompose the product $x_1 x_2 x_3$ and there is a theorem which shows how to expand the product with a minimal number of terms. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! I am a beginner in the field of CV quantum computing/quantum optics in general so I have a basic follow up question: in the RHS of the first line of your equation you have controlled-X operators that look like $e^{\pm i\frac{1}{\hbar}x_1p_2}$. However in on the LHS you have no $p$ operators. I'm guessing this has something to do with the Trotter-Suzuki expansion you mentioned? Can you suggest a good resource for understanding these gate constructions using this technique? Thanks!

Comment: @RajivKrishnakumar we switch out the momentum quadratures for position quadratures in modes $2$ and $3$ using the Fourier gates in the previous step. Furthermore, one can think of the controlled-X as a 2-mode translation operator with one mode controlling/generating the translations and another mode whose quadratures are being translated.

Comment: @RajivKrishnakumar a good resource for understanding the ST (Suzuki-Trotter) expansion is the original paper, "[Finding Exponential Product Formulas of Higher Orders](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F11526216_2)". As far as generally studying how these decompositions work, I'm not sure if there is yet any paper that deals with the n-mode case.

Comment: Ah OK someone pointed me to the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula (which I think the Suzuki-Trotter expansion is based on) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula. I guess to compute the first line of your equation $e^{-i\frac{s}{6\hbar}(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2}=...$ I'll have to compute the BCH expansion to see that it matches (or maybe just matches to first order?)

Comment: @RajivKrishnakumar I have edited the answer to include the ST1 decomposition. You don't need it any further than that and you certainly don't need BCH to establish ST. I suggest you take a good look at the literature once if you feel unsure about all this.

Comment: Ah sorry then I didn't quite understand what you meant by ST1 decomposition or I was referring to a different part. I was referring to the equation $e^{-i\frac{s}{6\hbar}(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2} = \mathcal{CX}^{\dagger}_{12}(1)\left[e^{-i\frac{s}{6\hbar}(x_1+x_2)^2}\right]\mathcal{CX}_{12}(1)$ For me being inexperienced, it's not so obvious that the LHS=RHS, and one way to show that would be to compute the RHS using the BCH expansion. Also I believe your construction of $\mathcal{O'}_{123}(s)$ is exact since all the terms in the exponents commute.

Comment: @RajivKrishnakumar the equation holds by definition of the controlled-X gate, but indeed, it is possible to explicitly show this by using the BCH formula.